# Is there any way to line up data in columns in python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have a coding assignment to line up data in columns.

Current code:

```
print('i i**2 i**3 2**i',sep=' ')
for i in range(1,13):
    print(i, i**2,i**3,2**i,sep=' ')
```

I have written this code.
Kindly someone help me to line up data in columns.

Comment: state your code as code in your question, give us an input and output example, then we can work on it.

Comment: Hint: try looking at [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust).